# How to make signup/signin process using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, bcrypt

Good day developers, I am new in backend technology using Nodejs and mongodb as my database. I am working on a project that includes a signup/signin page but i encountered some problems while creating a signup and the signin process. I will be grateful if i am redered help. Thanks!!

below is my server code:

```
const express = require("express")
const {default:mongoose} = require("mongoose")
const methodoverride = require("method-override")
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer")
const smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport")
const app = express();
const Blog = require("./models/blog.js")
const User = require("./models/User.js")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const JWT = require("jsonwebtoken")
const cookies = require("cookie-parser")
const cookieJwtAuth = require("./cookieAuth.js")

app.set("views engine", "ejs")
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fitnesblog").
then(()=>{console.log("Mongoose server has Started")
})
.catch(()=>{
    console.log("Unsuccessful")
})

app.use(express.static("public"))
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(methodoverride("_method")) 
app.use(cookies())

    app.get("/blogs/signup", (req,res)=>{
    res.render("signup.ejs", {title: "Sign Up"})
    })

    app.get("/blogs/login", (req,res)=>{
     res.render("login.ejs", {title: "Log In"})
    })

    app.get("/blogs/logout", (req,res)=>{
    res.cookie("token","")
    res.redirect("/")
    })

    app.post("/blogs/signup", async (req,res)=>{
    
    const {Username,Email,Password}= req.body
    console.log(Username,Email,Password)

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(Password, salt);
    
    const User = new User ({ ...req.body,password: hashedPassword})
    await User.save()
    
    const payload = {
        User: {
            Email:User.Email,
        },
    }

    const token = await JWT.sign(payload,"thisismysecretkey",{
        expiresIn:"3600",
    })
    
    res.cookies("token",token,{
        httpOnly: true,
    })

    res.redirect("/blogs/create")

    })

    app.post("/blogs/login",async(req,res)=>{
    const {Email,Password} = req.body;
    
    const user = await User.findOne({Email})

    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(Password, user.Password);
   
    if (!isMatch){
        return res.redirect("/blogs/signup")
    }
    
    const payload = {
        User: {
            Email:User.Email,
        },
    }

    const token = await JWT.sign(payload,"thisismysecretkey",{
        expiresIn:"3600",
    })
        res.cookies("token",token,{
        httpOnly: true,
    })

    res.redirect("/blogs/create")

})
app.listen(5000,()=>{
    console.log("server currently running on port 5000")
})
```

below is my cookieAuth code:

```
const JWT = require("jsonwebtoken");

const cookiesJwtAuth = (req,res, next)=>{

if(req.cookies === null){

    const token = req.cookies.token

}else{
    return res.redirect("/blogs/login")
}

try{
    const user = JWT.verify(token, "thisismysecretkey")
    req.user=user
    next()
}catch(error){
    res.clearCookie("token")
    return res.redirect("/")
}
}
```

and this is the error message i get when i hit the signup button:

```
jklassic0508 jklassic0508@yahoo.com GOD12345
C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\app.js:102
    const User = new User ({ ...req.body,password: hashedPassword})
                 ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'User' before initialization
    at C:\Users\go\Desktop\ejs\app.js:102:18
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: You are setting `const User = new User`. JavaScript is a [case-sensitive](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/javascript-the-definitive/0596000480/ch02s02.html#:~:text=JavaScript%20is%20a%20case%2Dsensitive,While%E2%80%9D%20or%20%E2%80%9CWHILE%E2%80%9D.) language. You are trying to set  a new variable while instantiating a new instance of an object with the same name. Try  `const user = new User`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in there.

Where you used `const User = new User(…)`
The variable to which you are assigning the new instance of user class should have a different name.